# Number Guessing Games with continuation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there is a solution to the number guessing game in python. I've seen the code here too. and as a continuation how can I add a function(or anything else) to prompt the user- after successfully guessing it- if he wants to continue or not if not halt it. I know the code don't know how to add it to code.

```
 import random
    def play_game():
    
        print("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: ")
        limit = int(input())
        number = random.randint(1, limit)
        print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
        count = 1
        while True:
            guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
            if guess < number:
                print("Too low.")
            elif guess > number:
                print("Too high.")
            elif guess == number:
                print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
                return
            count+=1
```

so here is what we had in this forum but how can I add this to what I have above :

```
ask = input('do you want to continue? y stands for yes and n for discontinuing')
    if ask=="y":
        UserGuess=int(input('Enter youre desired Number: '))
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include it in a `while` loop **outside** the function. This way, you will get recursion out of the way.

```
def play_game():
    ....
    ....
    count+=1

play_game()
while True:
    ask = input('do you want to continue? y stands for yes and n for discontinuing')
    if ask=="y":
        play_game()
    else:
        break
```